# How can I delete old backup via cron?

Tags: google-app-engine, backup

I'm using GAE/J and taking backup via cron.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups

Taking backup is possible by API (/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create), but I could not find a way to delete backup by API.

I already tried "backup.delete", but it was not worked.

Does someone know the way to delete old backup via cron?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Datastore Admin page, select some backups, and hit delete you will see that the page it takes you to has a form on it with hidden fields. That form POSTs the backup IDs (as separate fields with the same name "backup_id") to this URL: `/_ah/datastore_admin/backup_delete.do`

The backup_id's are the keys of _AE_Backup_Information entities in the datastore.

I have not tried using it yet. The form uses a XSRF token.